# Require attribute as soon as there's more than one element

Tags: xml, xsd

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code:

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="tiles" type="tiles" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xs:element name="tiles" type="tiles-with-key" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:choice>
```

I want to require a `key` attribute as soon as there is more than one `tiles` element:

```
<!-- one element, no need for the "key" attribute -->
<tiles>
    ...
</tiles>

<!-- two elements, we need the "key" to differentiate them -->
<tiles key="1">
    ...
</tiles>
<tiles key="2">
    ...
</tiles>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Unique Particle Attribution (UPA) which basically says the parser must know where it is in the model without look ahead. It this case, the tag name being the same between the options of your choice, the parser wouldn't know what model to apply.

Your question is basically to control the use of the attribute (required vs. optional) based on an external condition, here the count of tiles element. This is simply not possible with XSD 1.0. Schematron with XSD 1.0 would be one option; others may suggest XSD 1.1, too early to find a feasible solution here since support for it is rather low.